# Add plus symbol that cannot be edited in text field in ios (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, textfield

I need to create text field on storyboard with a symbol that will appear but will not be editable.

For example, we have a phone number country code +44. The user can edit 44 but "+" cannot be erased.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend setting the "+" as text within a `UILabel` and setting that label as the `leftView` of your text field. For example, in Objective-C:

```
UILabel *plusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
plusLabel.text = @" +";
[plusLabel sizeToFit];
self.textField.leftView = plusLabel;
self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

And in Swift:

```
let plusLabel = UILabel()
plusLabel.text = " +"
plusLabel.sizeToFit()
textField.leftView = plusLabel
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Comment: This is convenient if the "+" does not actually need to be a part of the text. Of course you could append that any time the text field's text property is accessed.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh Yeah, I'd recommend doing it this way (and appending the + to the text afterwards if need be) because if it's actually part of the text field, there are more cases to handle than your solution provides as is... For example, with your current code, if the user decides to start typing before the "+" or if they want to delete the "+" after entering text, they can; and generally speaking it's probably best if the +'s not selectable and if the user's not able to move the text caret before it, so those cases would also need to be handled...probably in `textViewDidChangeSelection`.

Comment: This does provide that for sure, and probably addresses the simple case presented by this question. It would be wise for the view controller then to have a method that is used to access the text field's text property and appends the "+" instead of doing it manually everywhere. Another option would be to use `[text hasPrefix:@"+"]` if the "+" must always be first. But in the case where a specific character just needs to be included (though not constrained to being first character) `[text rangeOfString:@"+"].location != NSNotFound` may be better still.

Comment: I ended up using this solution as it much easier for this specific case. However, I agree that for general cases @AndrewMonshizadeh's solution is probably better.

Comment: @AndrewMarin I actually answered a similar question yesterday about utilizing shouldChangeCharactersInRange while maintaining a prefix just in case you want to work off of Andrew's solution in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27673755/2274694

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` method on the `UITextField`'s delegate to determine if a specific change to the characters in the text field should be allowed.  With that method you can compose the proposed final string by way of `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)replacement`.

```
NSString *finalText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

Then you can compare that final text string with an empty string, if they are the same, return `NO`. This assumes your text field's text starts with the "+" in it.

```
if ([finalString isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
```