# Prevent prefix from deleting during shouldChangeTextInRange

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I've got a `UITextView` that has a prefix containing a 4 character whitespace string as an indent. If I type a lot of text and then hold the backspace button down for about a second, it deletes text at a rapid pace word by word, but it also deletes my "seperator space" which then causes my `UITextView` to be stuck and not able to type anymore.

This is the catch that I'm talking about:

```
if (range.location <= 4 && textView == self.descriptionTextView) {
    #warning fast deletion causes this to be un-editable
    return NO; // makes sure no one can edit the first 4 chars
}
```

How do I prevent such a "fast deletion" from deleting the "separating space" as well?

Comment: Could you post your whole shouldChangeTextInRange method?

Comment: That is my whole method, at least the contents

Comment: What do you mean by "the separator space"? And when you say "the first 4 characters are indented" do you just mean that there are 4 spaces?

Comment: Imagine a sentence 'hello lynsey'. I call the space between 'hello' and 'Lynsey' the sperating space (because it seperates the words)

Comment: P.S. Your method also includes "return yes;" I presume...

Comment: Appereantly apple programmed the fast deletion to stop after deleting one space or something equal

Comment: Yes indeed it returns yes at the bottom (thanks for pointing out)

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. And I see the problem with your current code. I'll write up an answer... One sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to maintain your prefix, I'd recommend figuring out the string that would result if you were to in fact change the characters in the given range, and then only allow for the text to change if the prefix doesn't remain as is; for example, in your specific case:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Combine the new text with the old
    NSString *combinedText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    // If the user attempts to delete before the 4th
    // character, delete all but the first 4 characters
    if (combinedText.length < 4) {
        textView.text = @"    "; // <-- or whatever the first 4 characters are
        return NO;
    }

    // Else if the user attempts to change any of the first
    // 4 characters, don't let them
    else if (![[textView.text substringToIndex:4] isEqualToString:[combinedText substringToIndex:4]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Or more generally speaking, to allow for flexibility, you can store your prefix string as a class instance variable then base your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` code on whatever that prefix variable may be:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Combine the new text with the old
    NSString *combinedText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    // If the user attempts to delete into the prefix
    // character, delete all but the prefix
    if (combinedText.length < self.prefixString.length) {
        textView.text = self.prefixString;
        return NO;
    }

    // Else if the user attempts to change any of the prefix,
    // don't let them
    else if (![self.prefixString isEqualToString:[combinedText substringToIndex:self.prefixString.length]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yeah so I thought about this solution but this would result in blocking the characters that are greater then the range as well. I was hoping to find a fix that wasn't interfeiring with apples ui/ux and just prevent the deletion of the space at all times

Comment: @bdv Do you mean that in the case of "fast deletion", if the user attempts to delete anything before the 4th character, you don't want to delete anything before the 4th character, but want to delete everything after that 4th character?

Comment: Yes, the use case of 'press and hold delete' is to remove all the characters in the field ( or many at least). The indented spaces are to make room for prefixed text that shouldn't be able to edit, so it would be bad practice as well if the user could delete those.

Comment: @bdv I understand about not wanting to delete the prefixed text, but the current code I wrote handles that... But what I think you're saying is that you also don't want the "fast deleting" backspace to stop deleting text if there are 10 characters left in the line... Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @bdv Oh, I understand now (I think)... Do you mean you don't want to be able to edit those first 4 characters? And if so, are those characters specific letters or are they just empty spaces?

Comment: You explain the problem well in the comment i upvoted! Not being able to select those characters would be very useful indeed. They are utf-8 whitespace characters (not spaces for the sake of linebreaking by char instead of word)

Comment: @bdv OK, still not sure if I understand completely, but you can try the code I just added to my update.

Comment: @bdv Glad if it worked for you. :) I also just edited my answer to include a more general example that would work for any length prefix containing any content.

Comment: Thanks Lyndsey that worked :) Yeah some const String would be nice indeed. Offtopic: I saw your facebook page and the sexist comment by a SO user. Just wanted to let you know that you must be a great example for women and girls learning to code. You've inspired me too. Keep it up!